# Gigya voting API

Tags: gigya

I'm currently working with a client that uses Gigya extensively throughout their site for things like ratings, reviews, and comments. We want to add the ability for the user to vote on articles. For example, an article type would be a recipe, and there would be a link to vote for this recipe as easy to make, and clicking on it would add a vote for saying this recipe was easy to make.

I'm digging through Gigya's APIs, and this almost seems like UserActions are what we want:

http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/UserAction+JS

They even have a demo showing it used for voting:
http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Reactions+Plugin+-+Voting+Demo

This is close to what we want, but not quite. The demo above has everything self contained within a widget. We'd like to be able to query the user actions and display them at the top of the page; while the ratings and voting are at the bottom of the page.

Also, we'd like to be able to tie the votes/useractions to users that also left a comment. Note that the site uses Gigya for SSO and profile management, so all users are kept in Gigya's system. For example, if User A leaves a comment and also votes a recipe as easy to make, we want to show that vote above their comment; showing it next to the user. However, userActions don't seem to support this. They also don't seem to have a specific API (other than JS) that would allow to just query this UserAction data on the backend. so it looks like I'm limited to just using the widget and accepting it's limitations or building a custom solution for this.

BTW, I know about comments.vote; but that isn't what I want either, as it seems it's just for voting up comments.

Is there some functionality for Gigya that I'm perhaps missing that I could use to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following to see how we have implemented a way of doing this: http://raas-demo.gigya.com/recipe1.php with reactions plugins.

Also have a review of http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Ratings+and+Reviews

It can be set on Categories

Kind Regards

Nadeem Rasool